# SMS Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent) returns null

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to read SMS on Android. Everything's fine except when I'm trying to access some value in `SmsMessage` object I'm getting an error:

```
12-29 17:41:58.762: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.android.internal.telephony.SmsMessageBase.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()' on a null object reference
12-29 17:41:58.762: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.telephony.SmsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress(SmsMessage.java:517)
```

I registered Receiver in AndroidManifest.xml, and by extending `BroadcastReceiver` created class `SmsReceiver`.

Method where I'm creating `SmsMessage` objects.

```
private final SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent) {

    Object[] messages = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("pdus");
    byte[][] pduObjs = new byte[messages.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        pduObjs[i] = (byte[]) messages[i];
    }

    byte[][] pdus = new byte[pduObjs.length][];
    int pduCount = pdus.length;

    SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pduCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < pduCount; i++) {
        pdus[i] = pduObjs[i];
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i]);
    }

    return msgs;
}
```

Method `onReceive`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SmsMessage[] messagesArray = getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

    for (SmsMessage message : messagesArray) {

        String sender = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress(); //the application fails here
        String order = message.getMessageBody().toString();
        //...
    }
}
```

I've tried method     `Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)`      but with no effect

Comment: Could you try checking that `intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")`?

Comment: In my code is the triggered action:         android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION

Comment: @EduardFűzesséry did you find the solution?

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner. I did find a solution, kind of... In my case all of this was becuase I tried to debug on a tablet without any gsm module...

Answer (score 4):

> I registered Receiver in AndroidManifest.xml, and by extending BroadcastReceiver created class SmsReceiver.

Since you haven't posted your AndroidManifest.xml i am assuming you are registering your receiver like this

```
<receiver android:name=". SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

if not please do it like this

as the [Android Documentation for getMessagesFromIntent(Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) says that it can only be used from API 19 onwards
hence ill tell you two methods to extract the sender's phone number and message from a received SMS

### 1. using `getMessagesFromIntent(Intent)` in your `onRecieve` method

```
for(SmsMessage message : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) { 
    if (message == null) { 
        Log.e(tag, "message is null"); 
        break; 
    } 
    smsOriginatingAddress = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
    smsDisplayMessage = message.getDisplayMessageBody(); 
}
```

### 2. using PDU (*protocol data unit*) – the standard industry format for an SMS message

```
Object[] data = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
for (Object pdu : data) {
    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
    if (message == null) {
        Log.e(tag, "message is null");
        break;
    }
    smsOriginatingAddress = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
    smsDisplayMessage = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
}
```

this should work fine

Comment: Worth noting that the second option does not reassemble message parts into a single message.